# How to connect to multiple redis instances with spring-data-redis

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I'm trying to connect with one springboot application to 2 different redis instances: one used as database and one used as cache only.
I added different connection factories and redis templates with different names and I'm using @Qualifier to link them. 
I tried to disable from auto configuration the class RedisAutoConfiguration, but nothing works.

I always receive this error:

> Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory]: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: redisCacheFactory,redisJitFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: redisCacheFactory,redisJitFactory

Can you give me any hint on how is possible to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're running into some version conflicts. Which versions of Spring Boot and Spring Data Redis do you use?

Comment: Is not a version issue. I've tried with different versions of springboot higher than 1.2.5.
I've found a solution by not declaring the redis connection factories as beans in spring context. I exposed only the RedisTemplate for each redis instance. In this way the redis implementation initiate its own auto configuration, but doesn't find any other connection factory.
The issue still remains if you expose as beans with @Bean two different RedisConnectionFactory instances.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is extracting the connectionFactory as beans. If you declare it inside template bean works properly. The following works for me:

```
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
    p:defaultSerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
       <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:host-name="${redis.ip}" p:port="6379" p:use-pool="true"/>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="redisTemplate2" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
    p:defaultSerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
       <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:host-name="${redis.ip2}" p:port="6379" p:use-pool="true"/>
    </property>
</bean> 

    <bean id="stringRedisSerializer"  class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
```