# Error while creating Bean even though the Dependency Bean is there

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have my Configuration Class with some Dependent Beans

```
public class WebConfig{
    @Bean
        @Qualifier("geojedis")
        public StringRedisTemplate geoJedisTemplate(
                @Qualifier("geographyJedisConnectionFactory") final JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

            // Create a RedisTemplate implementation which is basically of string
            // data structure.
            StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory);

            return redisTemplate;
        }

    @Bean
        @Qualifier("capacityStringRedisTemplate")
        public StringRedisTemplate capacityStringRedisTemplate(
                @Qualifier("capacityJedisConnectionFactory") final JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

            // Create a RedisTemplate implementation which is basically of string
            // data structure.
            StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory);

            return redisTemplate;
        }

    @Bean
        public JedisConnectionFactory geographyJedisConnectionFactory() {
            JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
            return connectionFactory;
        }

    @Bean
        public JedisConnectionFactory capacityJedisConnectionFactory() {
            JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
            return connectionFactory;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the below error. When i checked the configurations all are fine and I have also defined the `Qualifier` for mapping the correct dependencies. Any help is much appreciated.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type
>   [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory]: :
>   No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   geographyJedisConnectionFactory,capacityJedisConnectionFactory; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   geographyJedisConnectionFactory,capacityJedisConnectionFactory

Comment: Actually error message is clear : 
expected single matching bean but found 2. Use @Qualifier's for bean definitions.

Comment: @Habil I have defined the Beans using `@Qualifier` even though it's saying no matching bean found. same kind of issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621090/how-to-connect-to-multiple-redis-instances-with-spring-data-redis

Comment: Try bean def like this; 
@Bean(name="bean1")
        public JedisConnectionFactory geographyJedisConnectionFactory() {
            JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
            return connectionFactory;
        }

    @Bean(name="bean2")
        public JedisConnectionFactory capacityJedisConnectionFactory() {
            JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
            return connectionFactory;
        }

Comment: While a name() attribute is available, the default strategy for determining the name of a bean is to use the name of the @Bean method. This is convenient and intuitive, but if explicit naming is desired, the name attribute (or its alias value) may be used. Can you please explain what is the need to explicitly set the `@Bean("bean1")` for more https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bean inside RedisAutoConfiguration that is created if there is no default "redisTemplate" in Spring Context.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "redisTemplate")
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(
        RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) throws UnknownHostException {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    return template;
}
```

This one needs a single `RedisConnectionFactory`, but finds two.

As a work-around you can create a dummy RedisTemplate with the name "redisTemplate" and not use it.

Since it checks by bean name, the following could be enough as long as nothing tries to @Autowire it:

```
@Bean
public Object redisTemplate() {
    return new Object();
}
```

Comment: I just renamed my `RedisTemplate<String, String> geoRedisTemplate` to `RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate`. Now it's working fine. thanks @Yoory N

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the connection factory bean creation method instead of injection:

```
    @Bean       
    public StringRedisTemplate capacityStringRedisTemplate() {

        // Create a RedisTemplate implementation which is basically of string
        // data structure.
        StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate = 
             new StringRedisTemplate(capacityJedisConnectionFactory());

        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

This will point directly to the one your looking for

Comment: does this inject same bean that was created by Spring container?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski but we need to create the `JedisConnectionFactory` Bean and need to inject it otherwise the `afterPropertiesSet()` is not called so the connection it won't take from the pool instead it will create a new connection each time.

Comment: [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config) shows how Cross-method calls between `@Bean` methods are intercepted and bean cached in container is used instead of creating a new instance as we usually expect. Thanks @Maciej Kowalski

Answer (score 1):

use @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = RedisAutoConfiguration.class) above your config class and provide the custom connection properties